# Is it possible to integrate multi keycloak realm with single spring-boot application?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am trying to integrate multi keycloak realm in single spring-boot application to achieve multi-tenancy. is it possible to do that with Keycloak and spring-boot application ?

Comment: You should look at https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/securing_apps/index.html#_multi_tenancy